# Why should I avoid setting write access privilege for everyone to my folder in the Program Files directory?

Tags: inno-setup, uac

Why should I avoid setting write access privilege for everyone for my application folder like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Software\My Subfolder
```

in Inno Setup ? This UAC thing in my opinion is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 2):

Users should not be able to edit executables as this openes their system up to viruses and other malicious users.
With  the default security model, then any viruses that do get onto the system in the users account can not spread to other users or infect any shared files.

Further to this, your app should have no reason to write into the installation folder and all application data should either go into the user or common application data files.

Comment: Thanks on your reply. If that was the case, we should not have viruses on Windows 7, right? Yet, we do, and they are spreading like wild, no UAC can stop them. So, if my app was able to write to installation folder in all previous Windows version, and UAC isn't effectively stopping viruses, I would say it is a pain in the neck, nothing more. If I modify a sub folder, no harm done, right?

Comment: @Rawn UAC is quite effectively stops viruses. Yet some users think UAC is bad and turn it off thus making their system to behave like Windows XP. And by the way, not everyone on XP works under administrative account, and your application does not work for them.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov If it is effectively stopping viruses, then why am I investing 300$ each year for antivirus software on my machines? Anyway, it looks like UAC is a must so I must conform.

Comment: @Rawn There are a number of users who live virus-free even on XP without UAC and without antivirus software.